# why is this subquery not working? SQL Server begginer practice case

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_orders (
      "order_id" INT,
      "customer_id" INTEGER,
      "pizza_id" INTEGER,
      "exclusions" VARCHAR(4),
      "extras" VARCHAR(4),
      "order_time" DATETIME
    );
    INSERT INTO customer_orders
      ("order_id", "customer_id", "pizza_id", "exclusions", "extras", "order_time")
    VALUES
      ('1', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 18:05:02'),
      ('2', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 19:00:52'),
      ('3', '102', '1', '', '', '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('3', '102', '2', '', NULL, '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('4', '103', '2', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
      ('5', '104', '1', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:00:29'),
      ('6', '101', '2', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-08 21:03:13'),
      ('7', '105', '2', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:20:29'),
      ('8', '102', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-09 23:54:33'),
      ('9', '103', '1', '4', '1, 5', '2020-01-10 11:22:59'),
      ('10', '104', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-11 18:34:49'),
      ('10', '104', '1', '2, 6', '1, 4', '2020-01-11 18:34:49');
    
    
    CREATE TABLE pizza_toppings (
      "topping_id" INTEGER,
      "topping_name" VARCHAR(50)
    );
    INSERT INTO pizza_toppings
      ("topping_id", "topping_name")
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bacon'),
      (2, 'BBQ Sauce'),
      (3, 'Beef'),
      (4, 'Cheese'),
      (5, 'Chicken'),
      (6, 'Mushrooms'),
      (7, 'Onions'),
      (8, 'Pepperoni'),
      (9, 'Peppers'),
      (10, 'Salami'),
      (11, 'Tomatoes'),
      (12, 'Tomato Sauce')

CREATE TABLE pizza_names (
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "pizza_name" VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO pizza_names
  ("pizza_id", "pizza_name")
VALUES
  (1, 'Meatlovers'),
  (2, 'Vegetarian');

CREATE TABLE pizza_recipes (
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "toppings" VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO pizza_recipes
  ("pizza_id", "toppings")
VALUES
  (1, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10'),
  (2, '4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12');
```

And I'm asked: Generate an alphabetically ordered comma separated ingredient list for each pizza order from the customer_orders table.

- For example: "Meat Lovers: Bacon, Beef, ... , Salami"

So far I did this queries that separed work but when Im building it as a subquery is not working:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pizza_name + ':', 
    (SELECT toppings_per_recipe
    FROM
            (SELECT string_agg(topping_name, ', ') as toppings_per_recipe
            FROM pizza_recipes as pr
            cross apply string_split(pr.toppings, ',')
            JOIN pizza_toppings AS pt
            ON topping_id = VALUE GROUP BY pr.pizza_id)as o))
FROM customer_orders AS co
    JOIN pizza_names AS pn
    ON co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
```

when I run this it says 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'
but I don't know how to fix it and get the results I need (Im new in SQL so I'm a little lost here).

Comment: You have `"order_id" INTEGER,` then insert varchars? `('1', `... I would also suggest to NOT have ` `"order_id" INTEGER,` but perhaps just  `OrderId INT,`

Comment: Oh? When I created the table it worked fine (I was given this table btw) but Im just a begginer so if u say so Ill change it to INT then :)

Comment: Someone gave you double quotes around column names?  Look for another source to learn from perhaps.   Maybe you are uing MySQL not Sql Server?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss oh yeah I think the original is made for My SQL so I have to make a few adjustements. Here is the original table if you want to check it out 8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-2/ you Do you think is no good for a begginer like me? (and no no I'm using SQL Server, gor it from the Microoft page and everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you intended. When you write it to use a lookup then you'll need to restrict (correlate) to a single row. There was also another level of nesting that served no purpose:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pizza_name + ':',
        (
        SELECT string_agg(topping_name, ', ') within group (order by topping_name)
        FROM pizza_recipes as pr cross apply string_split(pr.toppings, ',')
            JOIN pizza_toppings AS pt ON topping_id = VALUE
        WHERE pr.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
        )
    ) as toppings_per_recipe
FROM customer_orders AS co JOIN pizza_names AS pn
    ON co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id;
```

To avoid the correlation you could use a derived table that generates the long names:

```
SELECT CONCAT(pizza_name, ':', toppings_per_recipe)
FROM customer_orders AS co JOIN pizza_names AS pn
    ON co.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id
    JOIN (
      SELECT pr.pizza_id,
        string_agg(topping_name, ', ') within group (order by topping_name) as toppings_per_recipe
      FROM pizza_recipes as pr cross apply string_split(pr.toppings, ',')
          JOIN pizza_toppings AS pt ON topping_id = VALUE
      GROUP BY pr.pizza_id
    ) as pizza_desc ON pizza_desc.pizza_id = pn.pizza_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ruGdPJ2c

Comment: @Stuck, yeah I was in the middle of adding that in :)

Comment: um I still haven't learn lookups, so Im not sure about that. Is that the only way? Because this is a practice for begginers and haven't need to use a lookup in the other questions

Comment: when I run this it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' I dont know wich one they seem fine to me?

Comment: @Ale, it's probably because I had missed a closing paren on the `concat`.

Comment: oh I didn't see that, you are right. And yess now is working! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can add the name drie4ctly to the ingridients

```
SELECT CONCAT(pn.pizza_name,': ', string_agg(topping_name, ', ')) as toppings_per_recipe
            FROM pizza_recipes as pr
            cross apply string_split(pr.toppings, ',')
            JOIN pizza_toppings AS pt
            ON topping_id = VALUE 
JOIN pizza_names AS pn ON pr."pizza_id" =  pn.pizza_id
GROUP BY pn.pizza_id,pn.pizza_name
```

| toppings_per_recipe |
| --- |
| Meatlovers: Bacon, BBQ Sauce, Beef, Cheese, Chicken, Mushrooms, Pepperoni, Salami |
| Vegetarian: Cheese, Mushrooms, Onions, Peppers, Tomatoes, Tomato Sauce |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/psPvqJFJ)

Comment: hey this looks really good, but there is a little problem, The final result looks like that but it has to be for each pizza order from the customer_orders table. all the 14 orders hehe

Comment: i didn't think that ypu struiggeld with that https://dbfiddle.uk/R4Y_Qkqg

Comment: I've been trying to solve this question all day, at this point I'm struggling with my name lmao thank you so much for the help!